# Nginx server blocks matching on ip

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have two IPs mapped on my host:

1.2.3.4 and 11.22.33.44 ("fail over" IP)

I'm working on a website that don't have a domain name for now. I'd like to serve it under 11.22.33.44 until I have a domain name for it.

So, I'd like to create a server block on Nginx that would serve only the requests sent to the fail over IP 11.22.33.44. (Other sites are already configured on the other IP).

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `listen` parameter in `server` block for that.

e.g.

```
server {
  listen 1.2.3.4:80;
  ...
}
```

And:

```
server {
  listen 11.22.33.44:80;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great! I'm going to try that!